# Toggle image src attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, imageurl

I am trying to change the HTML image `src` using Javascript. I have two images Plus.gif and Minus.gif.I have inserted HTML `img` tag and have written a Javascript function to change the image `src` when clicked.

Problem is that I want to change it back again when user clicks on the image. 
For example when the page is loaded the `Plus.gif` shows and when user clicks on it the image it changes to `Minus.gif`.

I want it so, when the image is `Minus.gif` and user clicks on it this should be changed to `Plus.gif`.

Here is my Javascript function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function chngimg() {
    var img = document.getElementById('imgplus').src; //= 'Images/Minus.gif';

    if (img) {
      document.getElementById('imgplus').src = 'Images/Minus.gif';
    } else if (!img) {
      document.getElementById('imgplus').src = 'Images/Plus.gif';
      alert(img);
    }

  }
</script>
```

Image tag:

```
<img id="imgplus" alt="" src="Images/Plus.gif" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick="chngimg()"   />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the changes I made to make it working

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function chngimg() {
        var img = document.getElementById('imgplus').src;
        if (img.indexOf('Plus.gif')!=-1) {
            document.getElementById('imgplus').src  = 'Images/Minus.gif';
        }
         else {
           document.getElementById('imgplus').src = 'Images/Plus.gif';
       }

    }
</script>

<img id="imgplus" alt="" src="Images/Plus.gif" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick="chngimg()"   />
```

Hope that resolves your question.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to add a *toggle* variable in your function:

```
var toggle = false;
function chngimg() {
    if (toggle === true) {
        document.getElementById('imgplus').src  = 'Images/Minus.gif';
    } else {
       document.getElementById('imgplus').src = 'Images/Plus.gif';
       alert(img); 
    }
    toggle = !toggle; 
}
```

---

Note that it's a better practice to use a sprite for this kind of thing.  If you're using two images, the user experience is going to be clunky, because the first time they click the image, there will be a slight delay while the second image loads.

Ideally you would have the two images as a sprite sheet, and be using JQuery.  Then you could just do it like this.

**HTML**

```
<img id="imgplus" src="Images/Sprite.gif" onclick="chngimg()" />
```

**CSS**

```
#imgplus .clicked { background-position: 0 -30px; }
```

**Javascript**

```
function chngimg() {
    $("#imgplus").toggleClass("clicked");
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should avoid the use of global variable `toggle` so the solution is reusable.

Comment: So Now Which Funciton I have to use `chngimg()` or `cngimg()`  ??

Comment: @user1583775 same one you're using, that was just a typo.

Comment: greatest solution

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully used this general solution in pure JS for the problem of toggling an img url:

```
function toggleImg() {
  let initialImg = document.getElementById("img-toggle").src;
  let srcTest = initialImg.includes('initial/img/url');
  let newImg = {
    'true':'second/img/url', 
    'false':'initial/img/url'}[srcTest];

  return newImg;
}
```

Then call toggleImg() inside whatever event handler you use....

```
someButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("img-toggle").src = toggleImg();
}
```