# Replacing image source on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

Trying to have a different image show up on a mouseover event. Using the following JavaScript:

```
$('div.row-fluid').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image1.jpg');
 }, function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image2.jpg');
 });​
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div class="span27 offset1" style="margin-top: -3.2em">
      <div class="searchbutton"><img src='http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image2.jpg''></div>
</div>
```

But no luck. What's the problem? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpmqm/2/

Comment: Well, you're not showing your `div` with the class of `row-fluid`, so that's a problem. Also, your JS Fiddle shows two quotes following the `src` of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `row-fluid` as a class name to your container. http://jsfiddle.net/mpmqm/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mpmqm/4/ - your selectors are off.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, you **need to learn how to debug JavaScript and jQuery**.

With both Firefox and Chrome, you can open up a console and type (note: this is not the same `$` as in your code!)

```
$('div.row-fluid')
> null
```

At this point you should realize that the selector did not work.

```
$('.row-fluid')
> null
```

Still `null` - oh, yes, **there is no `.row-fluid` element**.

Alternatively, you can enrich your code with debug statements:

```
console.log($('.row-fluid'))
```

should report that it has a length of `0`.

Comment: It's not `null` but an empty set (which should indeed make it clear, though).

Comment: You are right: It's the browsers built-in support of `$` which returns `null`. It is not 100% compatible to jQuery.

Comment: FYI: I guess you're using Chrome to debug. If you open the console on jsFiddle it will initally run code on the main frame (which uses MooTools, which `$` function can return `null`). If you want to run code in the result window you can select it on the bottom of the console.

Answer (score 0):

I did the job for another guy here on stackoverflow in pure javascript. The only difference from your case was that he wanted image src change on mouse click. Pls. see if that helps you in correcting your code:

[Toggle image src attribute using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225843/toggle-image-src-attribute-using-javascript/12225903#comment16381860_12225903)