# changing image with javascript within if/else

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change an image in my HTML, via an If/else statement, so the page displays an image depending on a value from another script
i currently have this code

```
<script>
      if (b.className="yes") {
    img src="Site/assets/HappyObama.jpg"
} 
else {
    img src="Site/assets/SadObama.jpg"
}
```

how can i fix this? Is there something within Javascript that does this?

Comment: You're aware of the difference between assigning and comparing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Because of the way the project is already build (with if/else statements above) i'd like to keep to that
otherwise, can you suggest a function or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle image src attribute using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225843/toggle-image-src-attribute-using-javascript)

Comment: What is `img` supposed to represent in `img src="Site/assets/HappyObama.jpg"`?

Answer (score -1):

Use a function to set the value for src.

```
function getImage(className) { 

    var image = "";
    if (className == 'yes') {
        image = "Site/assets/HappyObama.jpg"
    } 
    else {
        image = "Site/assets/SadObama.jpg"
    }  
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

     <p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>
     <img id="img" src="#">

     <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

     <script>
     function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
        var i = true;
        if(i) {
           document.getElementById("img").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg";

        } else {
           document.getElementById("img").src = "http://wallpaper-         gallery.net/images/image/image-13.jpg";}
       }
    </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Assign an id to your img tag, then you can

```
//First using jQuery    
     <script>
              if (b.className="yes") 
              {
                 $("#img").attr('src', 'Site/assets/HappyObama.jpg'); 
              } 
              else 
              {
                $("#img").attr('src', 'Site/assets/SadObama.jpg');
              }   
            </script>

//Second using javascript
 <script>
     if (b.className="yes") 
     {
        document.getElementById("img").src="Site/assets/HappyObama.jpg";
     } 
     else 
     {
          document.getElementById("img").src="Site/assets/SadObama.jpg";
     }   
 </script>
```

Lemme know if the problem resolved. Happy to help

Answer (score -5):

You can do like this

```
if (b.className="yes") {
   document.getElementById("imageid").src="Site/assets/HappyObama.jpg";
} else {
   document.getElementById("imageid").src="Site/assets/SadObama.jpg";
}
```